# How to plot the sum of this function series?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

Let us consider the sum of a function series
$$ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{z^n}{\left(z^n+1\right)^n}.$$

This series absolutely converges if `Abs[z] < 1` or `Abs[z] > 1` or `z==1` in view of the results of

```
DiscreteMaxLimit[(Abs[z]^n/Abs[(1 + z^n)]^n)^(1/n), n -> Infinity, 
Assumptions -> Abs[z] < 1]
```

> `Abs[z]`

and

```
DiscreteMaxLimit[(Abs[z]^n/Abs[(1 + z^n)]^n)^(1/n), n -> Infinity, 
Assumptions -> Abs[z] > 1]
```

> `0`

and the root test. Its sum presents two different analytic functions having the unit disk $\{z:|z| < 1\}$ and its exterior $\{z:|z| > 1\}$ as the natural domains of existence (see [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Analytic_function) for info) since the term $\frac{z^n}{\left(z^n+1\right)^n}$ has $n$ poles of order $n$ uniformly distributed on the unit circumference.

```
ComplexPlot3D[Sum[z^n/(1 + z^n)^n, {n, 1, 20}], {z, 2}]
```

[image]

illustrates it.

In 14.0 on Windows 10 I try to plot this function for real values of $x$ from $0$ to $2$.

Here are my not very successful attempts taking a lot of time.

```
Plot[Sum[x^n/(1 + x^n)^n, {n, 1, Infinity}], {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
Plot[NSum[x^n/(1 + x^n)^n, {n, 1, Infinity}], {x, 0, 2}, 
PlotRange -> All, WorkingPrecision -> 25]
```

[image]

Replacing the function under consideration by its partial sums, I obtain

```
Plot[{Sum[x^n/(1 + x^n)^n, {n, 1, 100}], Sum[x^n/(1 + x^n)^n, {n, 1, 1000}], 
Sum[x^n/(1 + x^n)^n, {n, 1, 10000}]}, {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

and

> General::munfl: 0.0000408571^71 is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

The latest  approach is not reliable (think of `Sum[x^n,{n,1,Infinity}]` and `Sum[x^n,{n,1,1000}]`). The hard piece is that

```
Plot[{Sum[x^n/(1 + x^n)^n, {n, 1, 100}],  Sum[x^n/(1 + x^n)^n, {n, 1, 1000}], 
 Sum[x^n/(1 + x^n)^n, {n, 1, 10000}], 
 58 - 163 x + 156 x^2 - 50 x^3, 
 Sum[x^n/(1 + x^n)^n, {n, 1, 20000}]]}, {x, 0.95, 1.05}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

> General::munfl: 0.950002^13812 is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

```
Plot[NSum[x^n/(1 + x^n)^n, {n, 1, Infinity}], {x, 0.95, 1.05}, 
PlotRange -> All, WorkingPrecision -> 15, MaxRecursion -> 4, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

[image]

> NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit::seqlim: The general form of the sequence could not be determined, and the result may be incorrect.

We see the last two plots differ for $x<1$. `58 - 163 x + 156 x^2 - 50 x^3` is nothing but the wrong result of `Series[Sum[x^k/(1 + x^k)^k, {k, 1, Infinity}], {x, 1, 3}] // Normal`: if this series were convergent , then there is an analytic continuation through `1`.

So the question is: how to reliably plot the function under consideration on the real range $[0,2]$?

Comment: (1) Use 50 terms. (2) Show the error bound is smaller than you can discern on a plot.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Your instructions are of this kind: to walk on a tightrope, move so that your center of mass is constantly projected onto the rope. I will be waiting for rich-in-content and serious replies.

Comment: In the question even the replies of Mathematica were edited by an unknown to me person. For example, "General::munfl: 0.0000408571^71 is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost". In view of it I rolled back the text.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: `NMaximize[{Sum[x^n/(1 + x^n)^n, {n, 51, Infinity}], x >= 0 && x <= 2},
  x]` returns the input and a warning "NMaximize::nnum: The function value -\!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = 51\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(0.09146359257542153`\), \(n\)]\ \*SuperscriptBox[\((1 + \*SuperscriptBox[\(0.09146359257542153`\), \(n\)])\), \(-n\)]\)\) is not a number at {x} = {0.0914636}.'.